# Create Triggers that will get its new data to insert in a new table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

Database Server: Oracle 11g

I need help on how I will proceed on getting the information from the 2two tables into an **audit table using a trigger**.

I have two tables that has **1-to-Many relationship**.

Parent Table:

```
   CREATE TABLE "CLIENT_DETAILS" ( 
          ID NUMBER(12) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ENABLE,
          FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
          RATING NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
          BIRTHDATE DATE NOT NULL
       );
```

CHILD TABLE:

```
  CREATE TABLE "CLIENT_ORDERS" ( 
      ID NUMBER(12) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ENABLE,
      CLIENT_DETAILS_ID NUMBER(12) REFERENCES CLIENT_DETAILS(ID),
      REMARKS VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
      DATE_TRANS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
   );
```

Audit Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE "CLIENT_ORDERS_AUDIT" ( 
          CLIENT_DETAILS_ID NUMBER(12) NOT NULL,
          FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
          REMARKS VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
          BIRTHDATE DATE NOT NULL,
          RATING VARCHR2(3) NOT NULL,
          DATE_TRANS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
       );
```

PARENT TRIGGER:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "CLIENT_DETAILS_TRG"
      BEFORE INSERT ON "CLIENT_DETAILS"
      FOR EACH ROW
      DECLARE
      v_user VARCHAR2(50);

 BEGIN
      IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO "CLIENT_ORDERS_AUDIT" 
        (ID, FIRSTNAME, REMARKS, BIRTHDATE, RATING, DATE_TRANS)
        VALUES (:NEW.ID, :NEW.FIRSTNAME, NEW:RATNG, :NEW.BIRTHDATE);
   END IF;
END;
/
COMMIT;
EXIT;
```

CHILD TRIGGER:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "CLIENT_ORDERS_TRG"
      BEFORE INSERT ON "CLIENT_ORDERS"
      FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
      v_user VARCHAR2(50);

 BEGIN
      IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO "CLIENT_ORDERS_AUDIT" 
        (REMARKS, DATE_TRANS)
        VALUES (:NEW.REMARKS, :NEW.DATE_TRANS');
   END IF;
END;
/
COMMIT;
EXIT;
```

The Audit table has the columns combined from the CLIENT_DETAILS and CLIENT_ORDERS table. How can I input all the information into the Audit table using a trigger?

What I did initially was create two triggers. 
These two triggers insert data into Audit table when there is an insertion happened in the Parent and Child Table. But every time I insert data into the Client_Orders (child) table, I am having a constraint violation that the the columns in parent table is required not to be null.

Is there anyway I can insert data in audit table? Kindly give me some light. I tried to search but I couldn't find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: You have to insert a valid and existing `CLIENT_DETAILS_ID` into `CLIENT_ORDERS` to get rid of the constraint violation. But I don't see how this has anything to do with the audit table or the triggers. But I don't understand, why you have one audit table for both tables. If there is only a change in `CLIENT_DETAILS` is the row inserted into `CLIENT_ORDERS_AUDIt` (BTW, capitalize the last `t` or otherwise you'd always have to write the table name exactly like this and enclose it in double quotes) supposed to have null values in the order related columns? Why don't you have two audit tables?

Comment: A table named `"CLIENT_ORDERS_AUDIt"` is going to get annoying really fast. Regarding the error, please show the `insert` statement and the exact  error message, as *I am having a constraint violation that the the columns in parent table is required not to be null* is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: So your problem exists entirely because of the data model. One Audit table per actual table is the only way to go.

Comment: @stickybit sorry. It was a typo. It should be AUDIT (uppercase T). I have added my triggers. The goal is to input all the information of Client_Details table and Client_Orders table as part of the requirement in one row. What I did is I removed the NOT NULL property in CLIENT_ORDERS_AUDIT table because of the  Constraint that I cannot insert null values on the fields of CLIENT_ORDER table. So it is not possible to use 2 triggers and insert them in one table? I guess I need to raise this requirement to my boss tomorrow :(. Thank you anyways.

Comment: *"So it is not possible to use 2 triggers and insert them in one table? "* yes of course it is possible. But only when the structure of the target table is amenable. It doesn't work in your original scenario because your target table had mandatory columns which could only be populated by one of your triggers. One audit table per actual table is recommended because it is easy to understand, easy to query against and easy to implement/maintain (pretty much everything you need can be generated from the Oracle data dictionary).

Comment: Also your Child Trigger doesn't insert any ID columns which rather poleaxes its purpose as an Audit Trail. The fact that your Audit table doesn't even have a column for Child table ID also makes it unfit as an Audit trail.

Comment: hi @APC thanks.. I would go for one audit table per actual table. :) Thanks